# How can I delete a user's personal files and settings, but keep the user account in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I want a fresh start. I want my Windows and all applications to be like I am for the first time ever logging in. So I want all my personal settings gone.

I have a user account on Windows Small Business Server 2003 for which I am the administrator. This account I want to keep, because it has e-mail in exchange.

All my documents are stored elsewhere, not in my account's profile folder.

The profile folder on the Server is not accessible, access is denied.

My questions:

- Is this something which is done often / recommended?
- If I remove all files on the client in my user folder, will this be permanently synched to the server?
- Alternatively, I count recreate the user account and re-import all e-mail in the exchange store, but I do not know if that new user will be the "same" user.
- Or is there a better way?

Comment: "The profile folder on the Server is not accessible, access is denied." - You will have to take ownership of the profile folder with an Administrator user.   The answer to your second question depends on the configuration of your profile.  Based on the information you provided I can't answer that question.  What does your IT Administrator suggest be done, since any recomendation we might have, would require them to do it.

Comment: @Ram I am the administrator. It's the default profile folder set in the user account's settings. Right know it has no owner. If I change ownership to Administrator, will it work properly later on?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, didn't `Small Business Server 2003` reach the support cycle end-of-life in 2015?

Comment: @Run5k It did. Albeit your inquiry seems a bit off topic.

Comment: @FleetCommand - yes, but only just a bit.  Whenever I scrutinize a scenario like this one, I always preach to my protégés the principles of *"Troubleshooting 101."*  Essentially, that dictates that we have thorough situational awareness regarding the simplest aspects of the technical architecture.  In this specific case, that includes an operating system that the vendor stopped updating and supporting quite a while ago.  It could be a contributing factor.

Comment: @Run5k - good advice, however its not always possible (due to budget) to update software, and therefore some people will have to troubleshoot outdated software. I work for a company who could afforded to update a piece of software we had issues with, but just didn't want to (as it 'used to work') and tasked me with fixing it. It wasn't possible, my manager didnt like that - but thats how it is sometimes! If you have a car and the wheel falls off, you dont expect it to run ok because the wheel 'used to work'.

Comment: @leinad13 - We owe it to the users of the community, to point out the obvious, if something isn't obvious to the user.  Reminding a user that SBS 2003, is out of support, is helpful to those don't realize it.

Comment: @Ramhound absolutely!

Comment: I'm not sure this _access denied_  thing is because of an outdated server. I imagine this profile folder is around on recent servers too, who is owner there then? But all questions still remain b.t.w.

Comment: By default only the user that belongs to the profile directory and an Administrator (user group) has access to profile directories.'

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to delete your user profile.

To do so, you need to login with another user account that has administrative privileges. You can create a temporary account and wipe it out later.

Do the following:

1. Move the contents inside your My Documents folder (or at least those that you don't want harmed) elsewhere.
2. Log out of the account whose profile you are about to delete. Log out on all systems.
3. Log in with the secondary/temporary admin account.
4. Right-click on Computer icon and choose Properties. This should open the System Properties dialog box.
5. Select *Advanced* tab.
6. In the User Profiles section, click on *Settings* button.
7. Choose the profile you'd like to delete and select *Delete*.
8. Cleanup what is left of the profile both on the local computer and the server.

> The profile folder on the Server is not accessible, access is denied.

Use this temporary/secondary admin account to take over its ownership, change its NTFS permissions to facilitate access and delete its contents (exactly in this order).

Comment: The problem with your suggestion, is that if the user deletes the user account on the AD server, they delete the AD user account itself.  They indicated they want to keep the user account, because the Exchange account, has emails they want to keep.

Comment: @Ramhound How the hell is this the problem  with *my* answer? I didn't sanction such foolishness nor gave instruction as to how commit such a folly.

Comment: Can you act like a normal person and literally not have a cow over a simple observation?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll make it simple for you: The user account and its profile are two distinct albeit connected things. If you don't want to delete the user account, then don't delete the user account.

Comment: @FleetCommand - I think you are correct, unless there is a weird setup in SBS 2003. Ramhound - the Exchange data should be stored on Exchange server, removing the user profile would not affect the account and therefore exchange data would remain. Unless its stored in a local pst file of course...

Comment: @FleetCommand - I understand more then you think.  If the user's profile wasn't ON the AD server itself, your suggestion, would be the perfect answer but it is.

Comment: I would love this easy sounding solution. But; on SBS2003, there is no such profile for every user, so I think only the profile local to SBS2003 will be deleted, despite of its type being Roaming. And on the client side (Windows 7), there seems to be no such option. On the client, I can change the profile type from Roaming to Local. Should I do that for all users I want to "refresh"?

Comment: I think the man has a profile with a map network drive what he is asking is how can he remove the profile and keep his files accessible from the new one ( mapped drive I assume ) cause since the emails are on exchange they will sync with the new one once he enters his email so I think fleet commander provided the answer to the question as stated it has nothing to do with the user account on AD the question was misleading .